# Confusion in type conversion

Tags: c#

i have confusion in type conversion please help me on below things.

```
<%# int.Parse(Eval("VendorId").ToString()) %>,
<%# Eval("ListId").ToString()%>
```

what these two returns?
Please suggest me on conversion.

Comment: The more important question is: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The `Page.Eval` method returns a `object` (`System.Object`). So:

1. `int.Parse(Eval("VendorId").ToString())` is first evaluating the property expression `VendorId` (via `DataBindiner.Eval`), and then calling `ToString()`. The string conversion is required, because `Int32.Parse` accepts a string argument. You run the risk of having a null value returned here and passed to `Int32.Parse` though.
2. `Eval("ListId").ToString()` is doing the same as above, but rendering the result of `ToString()` for the property expression `Listid`, instead of parsing it as an integer.